# Redraw sunburst Chart after update the series

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, highcharts

I am trying to update the Sunburst chart series on the change of dropdown. But my chart data series is not updating. Right now When I am trying to update the chart just the tooltip is getting updated chart is not redrawing.
Below is my code and JS fiddle demo URL:
https://jsfiddle.net/n0y87osa/6/

```
var options  =  {

  chart: {
    height: '70%',
   // type: 'sunburst'
   renderTo: 'container'

  },

  plotOptions: {
    sunburst: {}
  },
  series: [{
    type: "sunburst",
    name: 'Root',
    data: data,
    point:{
      events:{
        click: function (event) {
          alert(this.name);
        }
      }
    },
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {

          style: {
            fontSize: "12px",
            //color: "#515151",           
            fontWeight: 'normal !important',
            fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
            textOutline : 0,
            color: '#fff'
          },
    },
    levels: [{
            level: 1,
            levelIsConstant: false,
            dataLabels: {
               filter: {
                    property: 'outerArcLength',
                    operator: '>',
                    value: 64
                },
            },
        },{
      level: 2,
      dataLabels: {
        rotationMode: 'parallel'
      }
    }, {
      level: 3,
      colorVariation: {
        key: 'brightness',
        to: -0.4 //Tells the gradation extent
      }
    }]
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
  }
};
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


$('#type_').on('change',function(){
      alert(this.value);
      chart.series[0].setData(data2);
      
      chart.redraw()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue reproduced in a minimal live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qrhpsbx5/

Error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')`

---

The problem occurs because you are incorrectly using the `index` property in your data. Highcharts uses `index` from data also to calculate the length of data, which is causing incompatibilities during data updates.

As a solution, you can change the name of the property:

```
var data2 = [{
    id: '0.0',
    parent: '',
    name: 'KSE ALL',
    customIndex: 32819
}, ...];
```

or store it in `custom`:

```
var data2 = [{
    id: '0.0',
    parent: '',
    name: 'KSE ALL',
    custom: {
        index: 32819
    }
}, ...];
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xnespquj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.data.custom

Answer (score 0):

```
I did destroy the chart and redraw it with updated data series.    


var chart;
function sunBurstChart (data1){
var options  =  {

  chart: {
    height: '70%',
   // type: 'sunburst'
   renderTo: 'container'

  },
series: [{
    type: "sunburst",
    name: 'Root',
    data: data1,
    point:{
      events:{
        click: function (event) {
          alert(this.name);
        }
      }
    },
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
    
      /**
       * A custom formatter that returns the name only if the inner arc
       * is longer than a certain pixel size, so the shape has place for
       * the label.
       */
          style: {
            fontSize: "12px",
            //color: "#515151",           
            fontWeight: 'normal !important',
            fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
            textOutline : 0,
            color: '#fff'
          },
    },
    levels: [{
            level: 1,
            levelIsConstant: false,
            dataLabels: {
               filter: {
                    property: 'outerArcLength',
                    operator: '>',
                    value: 64
                },
                
            style: {
            fontSize: "12px",
            //color: "#515151",           
            fontWeight: 'normal !important',
            fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
                        textShadow: false ,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
            },
            },
        },{
      level: 2,
      dataLabels: {
        rotationMode: 'parallel'
      }
    }, {
      level: 3,
      colorVariation: {
        key: 'brightness',
        to: -0.4 //Tells the gradation extent
      }
    }]
  }],
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

}
sunBurstChart(data);
    $('#type_').on('change',function(){
         // alert(this.value);
          chart.destroy();
          sunBurstChart(data2);
          chart.redraw();
        });
```